# Series expansion for innocent looking function

Tags: power-series

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}$$ is given, where $f(z)$ is complex valued function.

**How can one find series expansion at $ z=i$ with using geometric series approach?** It seems simple but first tries gives no result, i.e adding subtracting $i$.

Comment: can someone up vote so we can get some attention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to compute the power series. In each way you need to compute the series for $g(z) = 1/z$ using the geometric approach.

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{z} = -\frac{1}{i - (z-i)} = i \frac{1}{1 - (\frac{z-i}{i})} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-i)^{k-1} (z-i)^k$$

for $|z - i| < 1$. Now you have 2 options (I personally prefer option number 2):

1. Use the Cauchy product, i.e. use $$\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n \right)  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$$
2. Use a theorem about the derivatives of power series. The theorem I'm thinking of tells you that taking the derivative of a power series which converges absolutely can be taken order-by-order. Doing this, you get $$\frac{1}{z^2} = - \frac{d}{dz} g(z)$$

Both approaches yield the result

$$\frac{1}{z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)(-i)^n (n+1) (z-i)^n$$

Comment: Then here We cant use directly geometric series without additional aid (like differentiation), right? Btw Nice answer!

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz I think so, yes. Otherwise you would end up with something like $(z^2-i)$ in your sum.

Comment: what i mean was something like $[(z - i) + i ]^2$ then proceed. This works for some problems, such as if there is wild +1 in denominator, which cancels after expanding square.